# Excel opening doesn't work with reuters module giving 'compile error'

Tags: excel, excel-2007, office-2007

I have

**Compile error in hidden module: wkbModel**

when I try to open Excel (I'm running win xp pro 2002 sp3 with office 2007).

I tried to disable the modules and found that the one causing the problem is *Power Plus Pro Excel v5.1* by Reuters. Of course disabling the module makes the program work, but I need this module enabled. Probably this problem has been brought by an automatic update as, until 2 weeks ago, everything worked fine.

I need to find a way to make excel not throwing the compile error while leaving the Reuters module open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found this was due to an update to office. Rolled back and everything was fine.